# How can I use new <script setup> syntax in Vue SFC without template section?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-sfc, vue-script-setup

When I try to write SFC with `<script setup>` but without `<template>`, I get a warning in console `[Vue warn] Component is missing template or render function`.

**Is there any workaround?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuejs dev [answers](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12281#issuecomment-930013742), that one can use empty `<template>` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you need a Template or render function. Since you don't want to use template, You can consider using render function.

Unfortunately, the render function doesn't seem to work with setup.

```
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  render() {
    return h("div", {}, this.a);
  }
});
</script>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { defineComponent, ref, h } from "vue";

const a = ref(1);
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

For more, you can see [render-function(official doc)](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html) here.

Comment: I have several renderless components, so, its render functions are just `() => null`

Comment: @dmitriy-korobkov I have a question, if there is no render, why is it a component. If you must, try returning null in render function.

Comment: Renderless component is useful pattern in some cases. Now ought to returning `() => null` as render function in old fashion style.